# Why "integralis" over "summatorius"?

Tags: calculus, terminology, math-history

It is written that Johann Bernoulli suggested to Leibniz that he (Leibniz) change the name of his calculus from "calculus summatorius" to "calculus integralis", but I cannot find their correspondence wherein Bernoulli explains why he thinks "integralis" is preferable to "summatorius." Can someone enlighten me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a source where one can read what Bernoulli thought, or are you looking for a personal reason why someone might think he preferred this?

Comment: because it sounds better, its as simple as that

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but it's possibly due to the fact that what we now know as an "integral" truly isn't a sum, but the limit of an infinite sum. It's possible that Bernoulli thought that the use of the word "summatorius" was misleading in the fact that an integral truly ins't a summation.

Answer (score 6):

Bernoulli writes this to Leibniz in 20/30 April 1695. His justification for this choice of words is that "differentials are part of a whole" ("integer" being Latin for whole).

Leibniz replies (6/16 May 1695) that this appellation does not displease him, but that he considers his preferred term "sum" more illuminating and closer to the source of the notion.

See the Akademie-Ausgabe, III6A, pp. 348, 356:
http://www.leibniz-edition.de/Baende/ReiheIII.htm

Comment: Dear Victor: Thank you for this info. I have retrieved the link and am working on the full Latin translation, but you have given me the answer I was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the correspondence. Maybe, [this](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Kzp4zPIL8B0C&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=integralis%20bernoulli%20leibniz&source=bl&ots=4bdiuSg5kj&sig=KLFGfxH1Vo3Z0ciK5T-VnwsDNNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aIPtUaXYOYrNrQfFyoCwAg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=integralis%20bernoulli%20leibniz&f=false) would be sure, the initial quotation states the exact point. As for the reason, some say that it was to rival Newton on proving that he had invented calculus first. The Bernoulli's too were involved in the controversy.[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%E2%80%93Newton_calculus_controversy%E2%80%8E) page explains the controversy.

Comment: Dear Torsten: I appreciate your input and found it (i.e. your first "this" helpful. I am now trying to locate the full statements (Leibniz to Bernoulli and vice versa in 1696. Thanks again.

Comment: Never a problem mon cher! I'm happy that I am helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I have no exact answer to your question, but I can provide you with some background. In late medieval Italian the adjective "integrale" was already used; its meaning is "total, entire". It is derived from the Latin word "integralis", which belongs to non-classical Latin (6th century A.C., so definitly non-classical): it appears in some comments to Cicerone's works. The Latin word "integer" is classical, instead. It has the same root of "tangere" (to touch) and "tangente" (yes, tangent!) and it means..."integer" or "pure/untouched".

Probably J. Bernoulli used the word "integralis" in 1690 to specify the property of "totality" or "completeness" of the operation, as the integral computes the "whole" area under a given curve.

Euler uses "integralis" in his "Institutiones calculi integralis" as an adjective.

It is funny to note that in the 18th century Luigi Guido Grandi and Maria Gaetana Agnesi discussed about "calcolo integrale" (i.e. Integral Calculus) using the word "integrale" as an adjective, while Riccati uses "integrale" as a noun.

Comment: I apologize for the inartful wording of my question. To make matters clear, I am not seeking speculation as to the reason for Bernoulli's preference (for integralis over summarorius): I would like to see Johann's statement itself wherein he explains his reasoning for the change in wording. If you can show me the exact wording of this compromise (or provide a link to it), I would be much obliged. Thanks again.

Comment: I see: I found this translation of the original by Bernoulli: http://ebooks.library.cornell.edu/cgi/t/text/pageviewer-idx?c=math;cc=math;rgn=full%20text;idno=bern002;didno=bern002;view=image;seq=5;node=bern002%3A1;page=root;size=100 You can see that the word "Integral" already appears without explanation. Searching in the references you could probably arrive at the book on differential calculus where Bernoulli gave (I hope!) the explanation of his use of the word "integral".

Comment: It is the max I could find, right now. I hope it helps :)